# how to declare pointer to objects for non-type templates?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

please consider the following example:

```
template <int N, int M>
class MyClass {
    private:
       void myFunc(void);

    public:
        void callMe(void);

    };
```

I need to declare a generic pointer to objects of this class. The compiler reject the following statement. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

```
extern template<int N, int M> MyClass<N, M> *obj;
```

Why I'm doing this? I need to write a function that is able work with a generic instance of objects from this class, please see the example:

```
inline template <int N, int M> void MyClass<N,M>::MyFunc(void) { obj = this; };
```

This is the behaviour I want, if possible. 
Notice that it works perfectly with NON TEMPLATE types.

```
void ThisIsAnotherFunction(void) {
    obj->callMe();
}
```

Comment: Do you want [variable_template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) ?

Comment: Are you trying to alias a *type* or declare a *variable*? That is, do you want a generic way to get a `MyClass<N, M>*` given some `N` and `M` or are you looking to declare a `constexpr` variable that is available for an instantiation of a specific `MyClass<N, M>`?

Comment: Did you manage to do this for templates with type parameters?

Comment: Are you actually trying to extern your template? An extern template needs to be provided with concrete arguments. It doesn't make sense to extern a whole template. And you would need to extern just the template, allowing you to use it later in a pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

Your different template classes will have nothing in common. What you can do is have your templated classes share a common base class, something like this:

```
struct BaseClass {};

template <int N, int M>
class MyClass : BaseClass {
    /*stuff*/
};

extern BaseClass* obj;
```

If you want a pointer to a specific concrete type, you have no choice but to provide values for N and M in your declaration.

```
extern MyClass<2, 3>* obj2;
```

Comment: Appreciate, but not working.

From obj pointer you cannot address MyClass members and methods even if you declare public the BaseClass. For example: obj->item compiles with error if item is a member of MyClass.

Comment: @Alessandro of course you get an error, you cannot call arbitrary methods on arbitrary pointers. You need to provide a `virtual item_type getItem();` to the base

Answer (score 0):

Your question allows at least two interpretations...

I) ...you want runtime polymorphism

Different instantiations of the same template are completely unrelated types. If you want them to share a common interface you can use a common base class:

```
struct base {
    /* declare common interface here */
};

template <int N, int M> struct foo : base {};
```

II) ... you want a variable `obj` for each instantiation of the tempalte

This smells like singleton and I am not sure if it makes any sense to do that, but that would be something like:

```
template <int N,int M> struct foo {
    constexpr static const foo* obj = new foo();    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the records, I resolved by using the suggestion wrote by #user463035818 (thanks dude!). I created a base class with callMe as virtual function (refer to initial example). Thanks to all that provided their support. Hope to retribute soon.